# Generating SBM and degree corrected SBM in graph-tool

Tags: graph-tool

I'm struggling to generate an SBM (as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_block_model) using graph-tool.
The function graph_tool.generation.generate_sbm generates a multigraph which isn't what I am looking for and the function graph_tool.generation.generate_maxent_sbm has the following probability for the adjency matrix A: [LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhuDF.png) (I assume thetas are all set to 1 in SBM). This doesn't correspond to the case that I'm looking for either since we would need [LaTeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cknBq.png). Since graph-tool is a powerful library and what I'm trying to do seems to be standard, I'm sure there's a way to do this (maybe involving graph_tool.generation.solve_sbm_fugacities). Thanks for the help!

I read the documentation and the examples provided but in the examples there were imported graphs and I couldn't grasp how we do it from scratch. I also looked if there were any other functions for generating SBM but didn't find any.